# Possible to make g++ compile to memory?

Tags: c++, g++

Is it possible to make g++ compile to RAM, then run the resulting executable from RAM, instead of from the HD?

Comment: You could use a RAM-disk (in-memory filesystem).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Jason one would guess it's for speed. accessing an old-fashioned physical disk turns the computer into a mechanical thingy. ditto speed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It generally takes more than a few thousand lines before you start running into compile bottlenecks though, and disk cache is generally fast enough.

Comment: @Jason: a (trivial) Windows hello world is 59 147 lines with MinGW g++ 4.9.1, after preprocessing. using visual c++ 12.0 (2013) it's 283 420 lines. i would **guess** that that's more than a few thousand lines. it so happens that the nuwen distro of g++, including boost library & more, is less than 400 MB. so it can just be copied to a ramdisk before one starts working. i would guess somewhat instant build after that, if one also sets up directories for intermediate files on ramdisk. haven't tried it though.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a JIT (Just In Time compiler) instead? If so then check this http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling

Comment: What? How is a "trivial" hello world `59147` lines of code? Surely that can't be right..

Comment: @brandon: in the standard Windows command interpreter you can count lines using this command: `find /c /v""`. or of course you can use `wc` from some Unix-land tool set.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf A simple hello world on Windows shouldn't take 59147 lines of code.  Anyway, if you have multiple files, it's generally better to compile using `-pipe` with gcc/g++, which uses pipes instead of temporary disk files to compile.  If that's still not fast enough, creating a ramdisk with Linux (or BSDs) at least is fairly simple (`mount -t tmpfs -osize=16m tmpfs ~/tmp`).  If that's still not fast enough, it's probably time to start looking at distributed compilers and compiler caches.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Nowhere did I doubt any expertise.  However, anybody should be able to easily write a 'hello world' on Windows in less than 59147 lines of code.

Comment: @Jason: Alf is talking about the number of lines *after* pre-processing. Most of that looks like one line in the user's code (`#include <windows.h>`, to be specific).

Comment: @JerryCoffin My mistake, I read the pre-processing statement incorrectly.  Also, I didn't think he meant a full `WinApi` 'hello world', instead of a simple console 'hello world'.  That makes more sense.  The insults weren't necessary.

Comment: Hello, everyone. Sorry for the late reply. I'm writing a server that compiles and runs small snippets of C++ (it's for educational purposes). The main bottleneck, I figure, is that programs are written to disk, then read from disk and run.

Comment: @OP; I'm not sure you can truly avoid that. If many people use your server, then storing it all in ram is going to be insane! However, why are you "reading" the program? Do you mean reading the output through a pipe? Or???  You should probably put the details in your post.  OT: @Cheersandhth; http://i.imgur.com/Aow8Dvw.png <-- uses stdio.h and printf.

Comment: @RustyDoorknobs You probably want to confirm writing to disk is a bottleneck before you optimize.  For small snippets of C++ code, I would doubt the difference between using disk and using RAM would be largely noticeable by a human (~50 milliseconds).

Comment: Alright, I'll probably just write to disk. Thank you.

Comment: @RustyDoorknobs Assuming the computer has sufficient RAM, all of the writes to disk will be cached in RAM anyway, so that the hard drive's (relatively) slow performance will be hidden from you (i.e. the writes will complete 'in the background' later on, rather than holding up the completion of the compile).  Modern OS's are clever that way :)